# How to make Input text inline with Radio Button in Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am new to bootstrap building a web page .my code segment of HTML page is

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <p>Create a promo code</p>

  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
  <div> Promo description * </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div>Promo Type</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked></input>
  Instant Discount
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2"></input>
  Cash back
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionRadios3" value="option3"> </input>
Other Gratification
</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
  <div> Promo Value * </div>
    <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" id="optionsRadios4" value="option1" checked></input>
  Percentage
<label for="hello" class="inline">Upper Limit</label>
<input id="hello" type="text" class="inline" placeholder="Text input">
</label>
<label class="radio inline">

<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" id="optionRadios6" value="option3"> </input>
Fixed Amount
</label>
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

a screen shot of page generated by this code is

[image]
as you can see percentage radio button and Upperlimit label and text input are not inline to each other .i want to make them inline.can any one please help how to accomplish this ??

**Update**

i tried the suggestion in the comment this time my html segment is

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <p>Create a promo code</p>

  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
  <div> Promo description * </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div>Promo Type</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked></input>
  Instant Discount
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2"></input>
  Cash back
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionRadios3" value="option3"> </input>
Other Gratification
</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
  <div> Promo Value * </div>
    <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline" id="label1">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" id="optionsRadios4" value="option1" checked></input>
  Percentage
  </label>
<label for="hello" class="inline" id="label2">Upper Limit
<input id="hello" type="text" class="inline" placeholder="Text input">
</label>

<label class="radio inline" id="label3" >

<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" id="optionRadios6" value="option3"> </input>
Fixed Amount
</label>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div> Promo-code usage count *
 </div>
    <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" id="optionsRadios5" value="option1" checked></input>
  Unlimited
<label for="hello1" class="inline">Limited
<input id="hello" type="radio" class="radio inline">
</label>
<input id="hello" type="text" class="inline">

    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

and `main.css` is

```
#hello,#optionsRadios4#optionRadios6#label1#label2#label3 {
  display: inline-block; float: left;
}
```

and i am getting the screen shot and it is not the expected any other suggestions ??

[image]

Comment: try CSS: `display: inline-block; float: left;` for all of them
or try html: `size="20"` (for example) only for edit field

Answer (score 0):

Does [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/edetih/1/edit) look like what you want?